# "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" on array initialisation in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift2

I'm getting the error "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" when trying to initialise an array of UIViewControllers.

The relevant parts of my class look like this:

```
// ScaleViewController inherits from UIViewController
var scaleViewController: ScaleViewController? 

func myFunc(sender: AnyObject) {
    //...
    let masterVC: UIViewController = self.splitViewController!.viewControllers[0] as UIViewController
    let viewControllers = [masterVC, self.scaleViewController] 
    // Above line gives "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" at "masterVC"
    self.splitViewController!.viewControllers = viewControllers
    //...
}
```

Comment: Usually this error occurs when you're trying to create a collection type with mixed optional and non-optional contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
let masterVC: UIViewController = self.splitViewController!.viewControllers[0] as UIViewController
guard let scalView = scaleViewController else { return }
let viewControllers = [masterVC, scalView]
```

Comment: Not sure why this works. Need to look up the `guard` keyword.

Comment: It is just for unwrap your optional.

Answer (score 2):

In Swift, arrays are homogenous by default, meaning that all members of array should be of the same type. In your example, `masterVC` is of type **UIViewController**, while `self.scaleViewController` is of type **UIViewController?** (Optional UIViewController, which is different from UIViewController).

One of the options in your case is to define explicitly type for `viewControllers` array:

```
let viewControllers:[UIViewController?] = [masterVC, self.scaleViewController]
```

Comment: unfortunately this approach does not work as the next line in the code is ```self.splitViewController!.viewControllers = viewControllers``` which will only accept non-optional UIViewController array

Comment: I've just tried to explain why you're getting this error, and gave one option to resolve it. Surely you should find a suitable solution that works for you, but that should be easier when you know what the problem is.